# iOS API Reference History

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way to find documentation for deprecated/Changed classes in the API Reference documentation?

For instance the `NSUserDefaults` class changed to `UserDefaults` and with that all of its methods.

Example:

Old Way...

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setObject(someObject, forKey: "someKey")
```

New Way...

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard()
defaults.set(someObject, forKey: "someKey")
```

Again how can I reference previous documentation for classes that have changed?

BTW - The documentation for the new `UserDefaults` class still refers to it as the `NSUserDefaults`class.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/userdefaults)

> Class
>
> UserDefaults
>
> The NSUserDefaults class provides a programmatic
> interface for interacting with the defaults system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find it on Git.
[Drop NS Prefix in Swift Foundation](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0086-drop-foundation-ns.md)

[iOS 9.3 to iOS 10.0 API Differences](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/iOS10APIDiffs/index.html)

[Older versions of iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008244-SW1)

Comment: It doesn't list any method changes.

Comment: No. Those are listed in the docs you posted yourself. 'https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/userdefaults/1856122-standard

Comment: I want to see the `old` methods.

Comment: Updated in my answer, please check if it is there what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, the first link does show what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!